# Posting a list of objects that all inherit from a base class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following methods in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    FieldPageViewModel model = new FieldPageViewModel { Title = "My Sample Page", Fields = new List<FieldModel>() };

    model.Fields.Add(new DecimalField { Label = "F1 D" });
    model.Fields.Add(new DecimalField { Label = "F2 D" });
    model.Fields.Add(new IntegerField { Label = "F3 I" });
    model.Fields.Add(new DropdownField { Label = "F4 L" });

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(List<FieldModel> fields)
{
    return View();
}
```

My view models look like this:

```
public class FieldPageViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<FieldModel> Fields { get; set; }
}

public class FieldModel
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
}

public class DecimalField : FieldModel
{
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}

public class IntegerField : FieldModel
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class DropdownField : FieldModel
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

This is my view:

```
<h2>Index</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>FieldPageViewModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Model.Title
        <br />
        @Html.EditorFor(n => n.Fields)

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

I have an Editor Template for each type of Field (DecimalField, IntegerField and DropdownField)

Everything renders fine, the issue I have is my post. Using the fields object posted back I can't cast to each individual type.  So I can't get the integer, decimal or string value.

What can I do to get the derived fields in my post method?

Comment: You should write your own ModelBinder.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13277278/inheritance-based-custom-model-binding
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451270/custom-model-binder-with-inheritance-using-web-api-and-ravendb

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it that way. Becouse in the backgroud MVC uses it own `ModelBinder` and it can't find out what type you actually have.

You have 2 options:

**First.** Define your own `ModelBinder`. You can check [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/605595/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-Model-Binder) but i can say that in your case it will be really hard.

**Second** Extend your base class like this:

```
public class FieldModel
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; } //here also can be enum
    public string Value {get; set; }
}
```

And then you can get actual value with a reflection from this information. Note that you should place `Type` in `hidden` `input`.

Ether way it's better to avoid such things in MVC.